# What's wrong with the code below?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm learning from the book from big nerd ranch.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = new CrimeFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
}
```

Got a type mismatch error. 
However, if I call

> CrimeFragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

it will not work.  So my question is how to call a CustomFragment(CrimeFragment) using an id from the layout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "will not work" mean?

Comment: missing casting? `CrimeFragment fragment = (CrimeFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);`

Comment: So does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, i figured that there is a difference between import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; and import android.app.Fragment; it wasn't just about casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
```

or

```
transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment).commit();
```

More information:

The screen orientation change will cause the fragment update once more if it is create in onCreate method.
you can prevent this here:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null){
  CrimeFragment fragment = new CrimeFragment();
  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, "fragment").commit();
}else{
  CrimeFragment homeFragment = (CrimeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment");
}
```